# 502 Bad Gateway Foreach loop

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

hope for some help, basically i have a script that gets the latest posts from facebook users, and basically i check if there is any new post that is not available on my database, in case that this post is new, than i save it in my database along with the post id (this way i check if exist on DB).

But i have a issue with it, in my case i need to check a number of users, and this users keeps growing, in my case i have 400 users. If i go more thatn 100 users i get the 500 error of course, it is many requests.

So does someone have a ideia of how could i handle it?

My code: FarcebookParcer.php

```
public function facebook($id, $num) {
    //Set your App ID and App Secret.
    $appID       = 'xxxxxxxxxx';
    $appSecret   = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
    //Create an access token using the APP ID and APP Secret.
    $accessToken = $appID . '|' . $appSecret;
    //Tie it all together to construct the URL
    $url         = "https://graph.facebook.com/$id/posts?fields=attachments,created_time&limit=$num&access_token=$accessToken";
    if (Helper::get_http_response_code($url) != 200) {
        return false;
    }
    //Make the API call
    $opts    = array(
        'http' => array(
            'method' => 'GET',
            'timeout' => 120
        )
    );
    $context = stream_context_create($opts);
    $result  = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
    //Decode the JSON result.
    $dt      = json_decode($result, true);
    $posts   = $dt;
    return $posts;
}
```

CronController.php

```
public function socialfacebook() {
    $facebook     = SocialSnap::all();
    $socialparser = new FacebookParser();
    $appID        = 'xxxxxxxxxxx';
    $appSecret    = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
    $accessToken  = $appID . '|' . $appSecret;
    set_time_limit(0);
    foreach ($facebook as $key => $value) {
        if ($value->facebook != NULL) {
            $facebook_user  = $socialparser->facebook_user(substr($value->facebook, 1));
            $facebook_posts = $socialparser->facebook(substr($value->facebook, 1), 1);
            //Check if valid url
            if ($facebook_posts == false || $facebook_user == false) {
                continue;
            }
            if (isset($facebook_posts['data'][0]['attachments']['data'][0]['target']['url']) && isset($facebook_posts['data'][0]['attachments']['data'][0]['description'])) {
                SnapChat::where('facebook', $value->facebook)->update(['facebook_photo' => 'https://graph.facebook.com/'. substr($value->facebook, 1) . '/picture/?type=normal']);
                $post_current = SocialSnap::where('id_social', $facebook_posts['data'][0]['id'])->first();
                //return $post_current;
                if ($post_current == NULL) {
                    $post               = new SocialSnap;
                    $post->id_social    = $facebook_posts['data'][0]['id'];
                    $post->id_snapchats = $value->id;
                    $post->date_social  = isset($facebook_posts['data'][0]['created_time']) ? date("Y-m-d H:m:s", strtotime($facebook_posts['data'][0]['created_time'])) : "";
                    $post->type         = 'facebook';
                    $post->url          = $facebook_posts['data'][0]['attachments']['data'][0]['target']['url'];
                    $post->message      = $facebook_posts['data'][0]['attachments']['data'][0]['description'];
                    if (isset($facebook_posts['data'][0]['attachments']['data'][0]['media']['image']['src'])) {
                        $post->image = $facebook_posts['data'][0]['attachments']['data'][0]['media']['image']['src'];
                    }
                    $post->save();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    echo 'DONE';
}
```

Comment: `FarcebookParcer`? Check your error logs.

Comment: 500 is not a time out issue. You probably have an error in your loop when it comes to a certain member.

Comment: sorry for my error it was a "502 Bad Gateway"